# conversion of binary file to text file

Tags: python-3.x

I work with zedborad, from which I transmit some data to my  pc.

```
    void process_echo_request(void *p)
{
    int sd = (int)p;
    int RECV_BUF_SIZE = 2048;
    char recv_buf[RECV_BUF_SIZE];
    int  n,i,j,nwrote;
    unsigned char my_buffer[4];

    unsigned char  test_value[ROW][COLUMN] = {
       {00, 00, 00, 01} ,
       {40, 00, 00, 01} , /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
       {80, 01, 81, 20} , /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
       {82, 52, 83, 64}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
    };
```

I receive that data and copy it to a file.
The file content looks like this

```
\00\00\00(\00\00PQR4S@
```

How can I convert this to a format like this using python

```
00 00 00 01 28 00 00 01 50 01 51 14 52 34 53 40
```

The above data is from "bless hex editor"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> bytestring = b'\00\00\00(\00\00PQR4S@'
>>> ' '.join('{:02x}'.format(b) for b in bytestring)
'00 00 00 28 00 00 50 51 52 34 53 40'
```

Explanation:

- Iterating the bytestring with `for b in bytestring` will return each byte as `int` objects: 0, 0, 0, 40, ..., 52, 83, 64
- `'{:02x}'.format(b)` converts each `int` object in a string. The representation is a hexadecimal number (the "x" in `02x`) of length 2 (the "2" in `02x`), zero-padded (the "0" in `02x`)
- `' '.join(...)` glues the various strings separating them with a space

Comment: Hi Andrea, Thank you so much for your answer and explanation. This works. Thanks again.. :)